# I built my project using IntelliJ and it changed my classpath, how can i go back?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, classpath

Using IntelliJ Community Edition 2022.3.2 for Windows 10, I was debugging my webapp just fine until I decided to run some unit tests manually by going to the file in the proyect explorer, double clicking it and selecting "run".

After doing that, the remote JVM Debug I had been using for months stopped working in the sense that it no longer stops at breakpoints even though it shows its connected.

After quite some digging I found that IntelliJ builds the project before running the tests [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1mLx.png) and therefore messes up my Java classpath. Normally I build my project via CMD using maven (mvn package and then mvn install) to install the built project in my local maven repository and that's where IntelliJ picks ups the classes but now it's picking up the classes that are the product of that build that happened because of that unit test run.

To give more context, my project is called "JavaClasses" and when I run mvn install each of the folders that are direct childs to the JavaClasses folder gets installed in my local maven repository and the output in the terminal is something like this for each child

```
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\Genexus\JavaClasses\gxcloudstorage-tests\target\gxcloudstorage-tests-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\MyUsername\.m2\repository\com\genexus\gxcloud
storage-tests\2.10-SNAPSHOT\gxcloudstorage-tests-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\Genexus\JavaClasses\gxcloudstorage-tests\.flattened-pom.xml to C:\Users\MyUsername\.m2\repository\com\genexus\gxcloudstorage-tests\2.10-SNAPSHOT
\gxcloudstorage-tests-2.10-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

So my question is, how can I go back? I would assume it´s a Java thing because there is no way for the IDE to know which copy of the class gets loaded

The route to the parent folder of the project in maven local repository is `C:\Users\MyUsername\.m2\repository\com` so I tried setting my classpath via CMD like this `set classpath=C:\Users\MyUsername\.m2\repository\com` but it did not work

Comment: No, you should not be adding the .m2 to your CLASSPATH.  IntelliJ will use Maven to add external libraries to your project correctly.  You will see them under dependencies in the Maven window and external libraries in the project window.

Comment: How can I fix the problem then? I can´t seem to find a way to go back work with what I have in my maven local repository

Comment: You weren't using Maven properly before if you had that CLASSPATH.  I would make it work without changing CLASSPATH.  It's not clear to me what debugging your web app means.  Are you debugging locally or connecting to remote instance?